Understanding the Definitions of Smoothness for Maps Between Manifolds: Ambiguities Regarding Charts and Atlases
I am encountering some difficulties in understanding definitions of smoothness.

$\textbf{Definition}$ : Let $F : M \rightarrow N$ be a map between two smooth manifold and let $p$ be an element of $M$. We say that $F$ is locally smooth around $p$ if there exists a map $(U,\Phi)$ around $p$ and a map $(V, \psi)$ around $F(p)$ such that $F(U) \subseteq V$ and $\psi \circ F \circ \Phi^{-1}$ is smooth (on $\Phi(U)$).


We say that $F$ is smooth on $M$ if $F$ is smooth on any point of $M$

My teacher first said that we can replace the "there exists" by a "for all". But, if the charts, coming from the definition for a point $p$, are $(U_1,\Phi_1)$ and $(V_1, \psi_1)$ and I try to prove that it is also true for any other couple $(U_2,\Phi_2)$ and $(V_2, \psi_2)$ around $p$ and $F(p)$, I will intuitively think of $\psi_2 \circ F \circ \phi_2^{-1}$ as $\psi_2 \circ \psi_1^{-1} \circ \psi_1 \circ F \circ \phi_1^{-1} \circ \phi_1\circ \phi_2^{-1}$ and with transition map I can see that $\psi_2 \circ F \circ \phi_2^{-1}$ is smooth on $\phi_2 (U_1 \cap U_2)$ but I don't know about $\phi_2 (U_2)$.
If I am assuming $F$ smooth on $M$ it is okay on all $\phi_2 (U_2)$ because what I proved is that $\psi_2 \circ F \circ \phi_2^{-1}$ is smooth locally around $p$ and I can do it for every point of $\phi_2 (U_2)$, not only $p$. But if not, I feel like I can't totally pass from "there exists" to "for all" at no cost. I will only have that $\psi \circ F \circ \Phi$ is smooth around $F(p)$ and not on $\phi(U)$.
Secondly, we also gave two equivalent definitions on which I have also questions :

F smooth on M $\iff$ $\forall p \in M$, there exists $(U,\phi)$ a chart containing $p$ and a chart $(V,\psi)$ containing $F(p)$ such that $U \cap F^{-1}(V)$ is open in $M$ et $\psi \circ F \circ \phi^{-1}$ is smooth from $\phi(U \cap F^{-1}(V))$ to $\psi(V)$

$\textbf{Question 1 }$ : I feel like this is true only if I am working with a maximal atlas so that if $(U,\phi)$ is a smooth chart $(U^{\prime},\phi_{|U^{\prime}})$ is also a smooth chart. Is this a thing that we often do to suppose we work with the maximal atlas (like we fix an atlas, and then we suppose it is the unique maximal one that we can derive from the one we fixed). Because, with adding all these map is there not a risk that some smooth function are added when I pass to the maximal atlas ? I think about the $F(U) \subseteq V$ condition, maybe it is not satisfied for any couple $(U,V)$ with the first atlases and now with the maximal one it is.

$F$ smooth on $M$ $\iff$ $F$ is continouous and there exists $2$ smooth atlases ${U_{\alpha},\phi_{\alpha}}$ (for $M$) and ${U_{\beta},\phi_{\beta}}$ (for $N$) such that for all $\alpha, \beta$, $\psi_{\beta} \circ F \circ \phi_{\alpha}^{-1}$ is smooth as a map from $\phi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha} \cap F^{-1}(V_{\beta}))$ to $\psi_{\beta}(V_{\beta})$

$\textbf{Question 2}$ : So this definition imply trivially the previous one so all I need to prove is that being smooth imply this. The continuity can be proved easily. But what I don't understand is that with the remark I did on the first definition why do I need to intersect with $F^{-1}(V_{\beta})$, it's true from $\phi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha})$ to $\psi_{\beta}(V_{\beta})$. If all I said is true what is the point of the last definition : saying that we only need to verify the smoothness on a smaller set. It seems a bit strange to me. I feel like I miss something.
